# Getting Duplicate while getting while exporting to CSV powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, api

I am using PowerShell code to hit public API but there is pagination meaning there are around  400000 pages but I am exporting to csv I am getting duplicate value.

My Code :

```
$uri = 'https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices'
$Headers = @{}
$Items = @()
Do
{
    
    $r = Invoke-WebRequest -Method 'Get' -uri $uri -Header $Headers -UseBasicParsing # -Verbose
    $c = $r.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
    $Items += $c.Items
    $Count += $c.Count
    $uri = $c.NextPageLink
    $uri
} While ($c.NextPageLink)
$Items | Export-CSV -Path ("$(get-date -format "Retail_yyyy_mm")" +'.csv') -Force
```

When I am checking the csv file there 100000 records that are duplicate. can someone guide me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for this API endpoint (here)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices] you are going to want to apply some filters, looking at the results of your code it will not be duplicating but in fact it will be showing every type of resource for every currency for every denomination of period of time etc thus the data will be very verbose.

Comment: Great analysis, @CraftyB. Your link got mangled; here's the correct one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices

Comment: I tried that still I am getting duplicate . when I check the manually in api I didn't found any duplicate from azure side

Comment: Please give an example of duplicates within your question (inclusive of all fields.), I can reassure you've I'm sampled enough data to ensure that the data alone for currency USD has 100k+ entries.

Comment: it is random duplicate can you try running above code and check duplicate.